# Trouble displaying links using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web

I'm trying to display a list of links that I parsed, it displays 1, when deriving a variable **linkvideo2** I get the result in the form of the first link to the video. Maybe you can't use CSS_SELECTOR with a loop?)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time 

name = 'hello world'
profile_path = r"C:/Users/Федорчик/Desktop"
options=Options()
options.set_preference('profile', profile_path)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
#driver = webdriver.Firefox(r"C:/Users/Федорчик/Desktop")
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com')
id_serth = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "search_query")
id_serth.send_keys(name)
button_serth = driver.find_element(By.ID, "search-icon-legacy")
time.sleep(4)
button_serth.click()
time.sleep(4)
button_filtr = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME ,"ytd-toggle-button-renderer")
button_filtr.click()
time.sleep(4)
button_filtrtode=driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ytd-search-filter-renderer")
button_filtrtode.click()
time.sleep(4)

urltek = driver.current_url


linkvideo2 = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ytd-video-renderer.style-scope:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > h3:nth-child(1) > a:nth-child(2)')
links=[]
for i in linkvideo2:
    links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
print(len(links))

print (urltek)
```

Answer:

```
1
https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=hello+world&sp=EgIIAQ%253D%253D
```

I will be very grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

better find by ID

```
linkvideo2 = driver.find_elements(By.ID, 'video-title')
links=[]
for i in linkvideo2:
    links.append(i.get_attribute('href'))
print(len(links))

print(urltek)
print(links)
```

output of "links" will be something like this:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, 'https://www.youtube.com/shorts/uXMjlXBW_fg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0a7AWgo6CY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEgOG1fZwoM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXFdprzIxvc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82YAs_viROM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgRObNaGhAg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFLPNXJU4KY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=64Wo6zQDgQ0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SpvI9648RrU', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wUw-rh97fso', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7XDmQsf1-A', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3md7eviZC_Y', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wklkXDhb6MQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82wxikm2CwI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1DVUYcE43A', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvFgCJqpxWI', 'https://www.youtube.com/shorts/8cfy5DjIS10', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5RV3unTmyTA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sjgee-HCCxs', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vUGQsCQNUgs']
```